# Get the user id via javascript

Tags: 2010, javascript

How can you get the current users id using javascript? Can you do this any JS file or does it need to be added at a certain point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite is to use the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) jQuery library, specifically the [GetCurrentuser operation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working on 2010 version you can use [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx) to get current user (and some other cool stuff).

Here is link to simple example:

- [SharePoint 2010 ECMAScript - How to know logged in user
  information](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-ecmascript-how-to-know_26.html)

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
    var context = null;
    var web = null;
    var currentUser = null;

    function getWebUserData() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        currentUser.retrieve();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), 
             Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
    }

    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
        var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
        alert('User name:' + userObject.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + 
                 userObject.get_loginName());
    }

    function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share: If you are looking for the ID of the current user only, there is no need to use any framework or API - SharePoint (at least in 2010, don't know in other versions) saves the ID in a global javascript variable named '_spUserId'.