# Getting the username from javascript client object model?

Tags: client-object-model

How do I go about getting the client username with the javascript client object model? I can't find anything helpful in microsoft's documentation, it's awful :|

Comment: Duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20802/get-the-user-id-via-javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
ctx.load(user);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    console.log(user);
});​
```

Comment: Slightly different approach than what @vedran-rasol did in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20802/get-the-user-id-via-javascript