# How to get the Login Name of user from people picker control using jquery?

Tags: 2013, jquery, people-picker, user-accounts, login

I want to get the log-in name of user from people picker control using jquery.

I have a code which displays the display name of the user but I am not able to get the login name.

Code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[title='Project Owner']").focusout(function () {    

    var loginName = $("span.ms-entity-resolved").attr("title");

    alert("Login Name:" + loginName);

    var displayName = $("span.ms-entity-resolved div:first-child").attr("displaytext");

    alert("Display Name :" +displayName);

});

});
```

Here Project Owner is name of the PeoplePicker control.

How do I get the login name?

Answer (score 1):

I did some tricks and found the solution finally, I don't know it is the optimal solution but it works in my case.

The code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[title='Project Owner']").focusout(function () {    

    var loginName = $("span.ms-entity-resolved").attr("ID");

    var start = loginName.indexOf(":");

    var end = loginName.indexOf("_Processed");

    var finalUserName = loginName.substring(start-1, end);

    alert(finalUserName);
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
ctx.load(user);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    alert(user);
});​
```

above is using sharepoint javascript object model sp.js, you cant do it the way your doing it in your example!

[Getting the username from javascript client object model?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45661/getting-the-username-from-javascript-client-object-model)

also look here:

[Get current user in Client Object Model with javascript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/get-current-user-in-client-object-model-with-javascript)

**EDIT**

sorry i missunderstood your question!

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
     $("input[title='JM ID']").focus(function()   
     { 
          var User = $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val(); 
          alert(User);
     }); 
});
```

that should get the user name from people picker!

http://ronsp.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/get-value-from-people-picker-using-jquery/

**EDIT**

strange should of worked! have you tried the full code?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
   $("input[title='JM ID']").focus(function()   
   { 
      var User = $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val().split("\\"); 
      alert(User);
   }); 
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
   $("input[title='JM ID']").focus(function()   
   { 
      var User = $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val().split("\\"); 
      alert(User[0]);
      alert(User[1]);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Will it get the current logged in user or the user that is entered in the PeoplePicker?

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: I tried the code and I am getting `undefined` in the alert box :(

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013...

Comment: Is not possible with SP2013?

Comment: it is possible! the above should of worked! make sure that user varible is populated or called properly like "textarea[title='People Picker']" is correct on your side!

Comment: I tried the same code you provided in update but I am getting no alert box. It just loses focus on next control. Here is my code: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[title='Project Owner']").focusout(function () {    
        
        //var loginName = $("span.ms-entity-resolved").attr("title");

        //alert("Login Name:" + loginName);

        var user = $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val().split("\\");

        alert(user[0]);

    });

});`

Comment: While testing the code I am entering single user value, but no alert box. :(

Comment: how about alert( $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val()); what do you get from that only?

Comment: The alert box comes up with `undefined`..

Comment: ok, you could follow this! its for 2013 as i think the val in the above method is wrong... I dont have 2013 machine atm to test what val it is in html! http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/sp2013-setting-people-picker-value-in-newform-aspx/

Comment: Ok, but I got that link before, but in this post there is already userAccountName, which I have to get from the people picker only when it loses the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can get login name using key property,

PickerEntity objEntity = (PickerEntity)peUser.ResolvedEntities;
loginName = objEntity.Key;

and Display name using DisplayText property,

displayName = objEntity.DisplayText;

Comment: This is using C#, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is alot easier - You can access a normal peoplepicker in SP2013 the same way you would access a clientside one.

The Problem is, that you need to know the ID to identify the peoplepicker.
Alternatively you can iterate over the global Object containing the PeoplePicker's.

If you check out the SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict object in your debugging console, there are all peoplepicker of this page stored in it (iterate here to get all peoplepicker).

[image]

You can access the entered user's information like this:

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[yourPickersID].GetAllUserInfo()
```

[image: Example User] 
Now every object has stored the properties of an user that was entered in the picker.

[image]

Here's an example for a group [image: Example Group]