# How to get the people picker value using jquery?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jquery, people-picker, edit-form

I am trying to get the people picker value on EditForm.aspx using Jquery. I have 2 people picker controls on Edit form.

I am not able to get it using jquery.

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80848/how-to-get-the-login-name-of-user-from-people-picker-control-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45661/getting-the-username-from-javascript-client-object-model

Answer (score 2):

You can access normal peoplepicker in SP2013 the same way you would access a [clientside one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx).

The Problem is, that you need to know the ID to identify the peoplepicker.

If you check out the `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict` object in your debugging console, there are all peoplepicker of this page stored in it.

[image: Example]

You can access the entered user's information like this:

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[yourPickersID].GetAllUserInfo()
```

[image: Example User]
Now every object has stored the properties of an user that was entered in the picker.

[image]

Here's an example for a group 
[image: Example Group]

Here's some code to iterate over all picker and output all users to the console:

```
// get all user from all peoplepicker on the page - without jQuery 
for (var propertyName in SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict) {
    var allUserInfo = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[propertyName].GetAllUserInfo()
    for (var user in allUserInfo) {
        console.log(allUserInfo[user]);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This is using the SharePoint Object Model - not jQuery.

Comment: @vapcguy why would I use jQuery to access a global variable?

Comment: Because that is what the OP wanted.  And I was looking for the same thing, since where I work they frown on managed code due to having to involve the server team and downtime during the recycling of the app pool, etc.  We're using SPServices to compare data on a form to a list  (the logged-in user to the requestor of an item on a separate list).  Getting the name in JavaScript is very helpful for that.

Comment: @vapcguy I don't think you understand - this solution is plain JavaScript. It is using the JS global Variable `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict` created by SharePoint. There is no "jQuery-way" to access a variable. But I'll create a ready-to-run example just for you. Just wait for it.

Comment: @vapcguy copy and paste the added code in the browser console on a page where a peoplepicker is present `// get all user from all peoplepicker on the page - without jQuery 
for (var propertyName in SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict) {
    var allUserInfo = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[propertyName].GetAllUserInfo()
    for (var user in allUserInfo) {
        console.log(allUserInfo[user]);
    }
}` :)

Comment: I get `SCRIPT5009: 'SPClientPeoplePicker' is undefined` in the console window.

Comment: @vapcguy SP 2013 and there is a PeoplePicker on the page?

Comment: Ok, I have a worse problem.  You're right.  They used a generic input but are supplying it with an SPUser object when they are filling it onload.  Different issue.

Comment: If its a simple html Input what is stored in the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27349/discussion-between-vapcguy-and-mx).

Comment: @vapcguy can't right Now - online with my phone. Why not Opening a new question?

Comment: No problem.  Was about to do just that.

Comment: @vapcguy Share the Link here and I will try to help you tomorrow

Comment: Thanks Mx - I figured out my issue - I was actually trying to pull the value out before it was populated.  The code was loading the current user via an SPServices AJAX call asynchronously to the rest of the  `$(document).ready()` code and had not finished loading into the box when the `ready()` code was trying to pull it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are smart when you have jQuery with you.

`$('div[id$="_upLevelDiv"]').eq(2).find('div').eq(0).attr('description')`

I have used index because I have more than two peoplePicker in my form.
I have captured the third `$('div[id$="_upLevelDiv"]').eq(2)` people picker resolved value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since in SharePoint **2013** Client Side Rendering (CSR) is the *default* rendering mode, i would recommend you the following approach of getting People Picker value in Edit form.

Assume a `Tasks` list that contains `AssignedTo` field, then the following example demonstrates how to retrieve the value of `AssignedTo` field in Edit form:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      OnPreRender: function(ctx) { 

        var assignedTo = ctx.ListData.Items[0].AssignedTo;

      }

    });
});
```

**Result**

`AssignedTo` value:

```
[
    {
        "Claim": null,
        "Key": "Approvers",
        "DisplayText": "Approvers",
        "IsResolved": true,
        "Description": "Approvers",
        "EntityType": "",
        "EntityGroupName": "",
        "HierarchyIdentifier": null,
        "EntityData": {
            "SPUserID": "11",
            "AccountName": "Approvers",
            "PrincipalType": "User"
        },
        "EntityDataElements": [
            {
                "First": "SPUserID",
                "Second": "11"
            },
            {
                "First": "AccountName",
                "Second": "Approvers"
            },
            {
                "First": "PrincipalType",
                "Second": "User"
            }
        ],
        "MultipleMatches": [],
        "ProviderName": "",
        "ProviderDisplayName": ""
    }
]
```

**How to apply the changes**

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx)
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

Comment: I don't know how to use this

Comment: Follow this article http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/ and see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

call the below fun inside document.ready ()

```
             var mPplPickerName=    getEditorPeoplePickerValues("your 
           pplpicker fieldname");
```

outside the doc.ready function:

```
      function getEditorPeoplePickerValues(fieldName) { // Field Title

   //alert(' inside get pplpicker sub function');

    editorNames = "";
    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
    var ppobject = 
       SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
       editorsInfo = ppobject.GetAllUserInfo();
          var i;
        for (i = 0; i < editorsInfo.length; ++i) {
           editorNames += editorsInfo[i].DisplayText + ";#";
           }
       //alert(editorNames);
        return editorNames;
   }
```

i have tested,  its working for me!

Comment: I get `SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined`. And that's after I added a `var` to `editorNames` and removed the unnecessary `var i;` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the related `<div>` in the People picker by ID:

```
var relateemail = document.getElementById('ID_UserField_upLevelDiv').innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had a case where I needed to get the value that was in the people picker field on page load, store it, then compare it if/when it was changed on the page prior to saving - and if so, set a checkbox field on the page so a workflow could grab the new person field value and send them a notification. I just used a REST call to get the value, initially, because if you try to get it from one of the spans, it won't be populated yet - even during the `$(document).ready()` event.

Set an array: `var documentItems = [];`

And a variable for a string of your original results: `var originalPerson = "";`

You'll only be setting an array of one item, but I found it was just easier for me since I use this construct whenever I'm grabbing items via AJAX.

In your `$(document).ready()`, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getPerson();
});
```

Then...

```
function getPerson() {
    // Get the ID of the current item
    var url = window.location.href;
    var urlParams = url.split('ID=')[1]; // gets everything downstream of the equals
    var id = urlParams.split('&')[0]; // gets everything upstream of the "&" separator: the ID

    // or you can hardcode it for testing: 
    // var id = 1; // must be a valid item ID

    var listName = "MyList";
    var url = "https://somesite.com/sites/mysitecollection";
    var complete, failure;
    getMyListItem(url, id, listName, complete, failure);
}

function getMyListItem(url, id, listName, complete, failure) {
    
    // Execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=YourPersonField/Title,YourPersonField/Id&filter=ID%20eq%20" + id + "&$expand=YourPersonField",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success, data: " + data + ", data length: " + data.d.results.length);
            var items = data.d.results;
            if (items.length > 0) {
                console.log("item: " + data);
                if (items[0].YourPersonField != undefined) {
                    console.log("found field");
                    if (items[0].YourPersonField.results != undefined) {
                        console.log("found results set");
                        if (items[0].YourPersonField.results > 0) {
                            console.log("found results > 0");
                            for (var i=0; i<items[0].YourPersonField.results.length; i++) {
                                var name = "";
                                console.log("Loop " + i + ", " + items[0].YourPersonField.results[i].Title);
                                name = items[0].YourPersonField.results[i].Title;
                                documentItems.push({
                                    "name" : name
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                buildContent(items[0].YourPersonField.results.length);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
}

function buildContent(itemCount) {
    var htmlContent = ""; // sometimes I spit this out to a div I append after populating
    if (itemCount > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < documentItems.length; i++) {
            htmlContent += documentItems[i].name + ";";
            console.log("Added: " + documentItems[i].name);
        }
        htmlContent = htmlContent.trimEnd(';');
    }
    originalPerson = htmlContent; // populate our base variable
}
```

This is set up in case there are multiple values in the picker and you will need to change `YourPersonField` to the underlying name of your person field - not the display name. It could be `Your_0x0020_Person_0x0020_Field`, for example, if you created the field with spaces in it, originally (never a good idea because of that).

Once we know what the original value is, another way we can get the value directly from the screen is after a `focusout`. In the `$(document).ready()`, I added the `focusout` event onto the hidden input field associated with the people picker:

```
var personInput = $('input[title="YourPersonField"]');

personInput.focusout(function() { 
    doPersonDiff();
});
```

In `doPersonDiff()` is where I grab the value:

```
function doPersonDiff() {
    console.log("Checking if person changed...");
    var personSpan = $('span[id*="YourPersonField"]');
    var newPerson = stripPickerValue(personSpan.text());  // parse it here
    console.log("Original person: " + originalPerson + ", new person: " + newPerson);

    // ... split newAgent on the "x"s, split originalPerson on the ";"
    // do indexOf comparisons on "newPerson" to see if "newPerson" is missing "originalPerson" array values you iterate over
    // and then an indexOf on the "originalPerson" string to see if "originalPerson" is missing "newPerson" array values you iterate over
    // If any indexOf fails ( == -1 ), set listChanged = true;
    // If listChanged == true, test if the field that represents a change was made is already set - if so, ignore
    // If listChanged == true, and the field that represents a change was made is not set, set it
    // If listChanged == false, unset the box.
}
```

I won't supply the full code on that since this question was not about how to compare strings and arrays. But I'll include my `SPAN` field text parser:

```
function stripPickerValue(person) {
    var newPerson = person;
    console.log("Span text: " + newPerson);
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Your Person Field','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Enter a name or email address...','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Enter names or email addresses...',''); // if your person field can contain multiple values
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('xSuggestions are available. Use up and down arrows to select.',''); // for multiple values
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Suggestions are available. Use up and down arrows to select.','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('\r','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('\n','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('\t','');
    newPerson = newPerson.trim();
    return newPerson;
}
```

That will clean up the span's HTML text. Even if your field doesn't allow multiple values, you can use this with all of the `replace` lines, since it will just skip it if it doesn't find it. Order is important, so that it finds longer text first and removes that, then checks for the shorter version, not the other way around.

So bottom line, either use the REST call if you need it onload, or get it on `focusout` and parse the content so you can get it when you click something else.

```
// in a routine that focusout calls...
var personSpan = $('span[id*="YourPersonField"]');
// Send personSpan through the parser
```

Be sure to override the Submit button in `$(document).ready()` so you can run that routine, though - `focusout` doesn't work if they immediately go for that Submit button after adding a value.

```
var submitBtn = $('input[name*="diidIOSaveItem"]');
submitBtn.parent().append('<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="doValidation()"></input>');
submitBtn.hide();
```

...and in `doValidation()`:

```
function doValidation() {
    doPersonDiff();  // or whatever routine you have that is grabbing the people picker value...
    $('input[name*="diidIOSaveItem"]').click(); // submit as normal
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to take site users by REST query. Store all users in some variable. Then in aspx page, use auto complete functionality of jquery UI.
You can use following REST query to fetch all users from site users

> _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUsers

Comment: The peoplepicker itself contains a lot of information. No need to request the userprofile. 
Keep also in mind, that the pplpckr can find a lot more accounts than the page knows. So its totally possible to get no results from REST.

Comment: I need to get the value of an approver group vaule in a fucntion using jquery.